Unable to start kafka after add more directories in log.dirs
I init kafka log.dirs with one directory in config/kraft/server.properties:
log.dirs=/data/kafka-data/kraft-combined-logs-0

I want to enable multiple directories, such as
log.dirs=/data/kafka-data/kraft-combined-logs-0,/data/kafka-data/kraft-combined-logs-1,/data/kafka-data/kraft-combined-logs-2

After config it in config/kraft/server.properties, got error below when restart kafka:
[2024-10-08 16:29:52,265] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No `meta.properties` found in /data/kafka-data/kraft-combined-logs-1 (have you run `kafka-storage.sh` to format the directory?)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer$.$anonfun$initializeLogDirs$3(KafkaRaftServer.scala:164)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer$.initializeLogDirs(KafkaRaftServer.scala:159)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer.<init>(KafkaRaftServer.scala:60)
        at kafka.Kafka$.buildServer(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:90)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

I know the directory is required to format, but does it impact the existing data with
bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID -c config/kraft/server.properties?
Is there a document about the command kafka-storage.sh?
Kafka version: 3.8.0

After a test, with parameter --ignore-formatted, the script bin/kafka-storage.sh format new directories and keep the existing data.
bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID -c config/kraft/server.properties --ignore-formatted

All parameters can be found in the StorageTool source code
